# Stretching a div across the width of the screen in bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I wish to stretch the div blue across the  width of the screen which is used inside a container class in bootstrap. Here's the code

```
<div class='container'>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/175/80/sports/1" width="230" height="70" class="pull-left" />
    <div class='clearfix'></div>
    <div class= 'padding-top'></div>
    <div class="blue"></div>
    <div class="padding-bottom"></div>
```

Here's the CSS for the blue div

```
.blue{
    border-top:3px solid #8DBF43;
    width:100% !important;
}
```

But the directive doesn't seem to be working, its still contained inside the container.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to stretch :

James answer is very usefull : https://stackoverflow.com/a/22556241/2454790

**Bootply** : http://www.bootply.com/123651

**CSS** :

```
.blue{
    border-top:3px solid #8DBF43;
    width:100% !important;
  height:200px;            // <-- height of div
  background:blue;
  position: absolute;     // <-- important 
  left:0;                 // <-- make div to begin at left
  color:white;
  padding-left:15px;      // <-- remove bootstrap padding parent (-15px)
  padding-right:15px;
}

.padding-bottom{
  margin-top:200px;      // <-- make margintop same as the height of .blue
    height:200px;
  background:yellow;
  }
```

**HTML** : *sames as given*

Answer (score 2):

Since the `div` blue is inside the `div` container, when you assign `width:100%` it take the width of the parent element, in this case that is the width of the `div` container.